# Pyspark - How to read only the CSV columns that match with a specific schema

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read a CSV file but I am not interested on all the columns and I don't even know what columns are there.

I am trying to use pyspark to read this CSV and keep only the columns that I know about.

So I have the CSV with the header:

```
A,B,C,D
```

And I have the schema below:

```
StructType([
    StructField("a", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("b", TimestampType(), True)        
])
```

Is there a way to make spark only consider the columns that match on the header and schema and ignore all the rest?

Comment: `read.csv` with `header=True` should work for you as long as the columns you want are the ones at the front. By default, it ignores extra data that doesn't match the schema. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried, but the columns I want will not be in front of the header, actually they will appear in random positions due to previous parallel processings

Comment: `spark.read.csv(fpath,schema=schema)` worked fine for me, ignored the other columns after the one I wanted. doesn't work if you want columns in middle though.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can load csv and then drop the columns also.

```
>>> df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(file_path)
>>> df.show();
+---+-------+---------+
| id|empname|empsalary|
+---+-------+---------+
|  1|vikrant|    10000|
|  2| raghav|    50000|
+---+-------+---------+

>>> newdf = df.drop('empsalary')
>>> newdf.show();
+---+-------+
| id|empname|
+---+-------+
|  1|vikrant|
|  2| raghav|
+---+-------+
```

can also load it via rdd and exclude/include the columns of your choice:

```
id,empname,empsalary
1,vikrant,10000
2,raghav,50000

>>> df = sc.textFile(file_path)\
...            .map(lambda x: x.split(",")).map(lambda x : (x[0],x[2])) \
...            .toDF(['id','salary'])

>>> df.show();
+---+---------+
| id|   salary|
+---+---------+
| id|empsalary|
|  1|    10000|
|  2|    50000|
+---+---------+
```

if you have Pandas library installed on spark:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(file_path,usecols=[1,2],index_col=0)
print(df)


empname      empsalary
vikrant      10000
raghav       50000
```